# Returning a page through HTTP with express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, http

I have a folder called "Public" which contains an index.html file a long with some JavaScript and library files. When someone tries to access the products path (mydomain.com/products) I want to display that index.html file, but the client also needs to receive all the JavaScript and libraries. Here is the code for how I initially handle the HTTP request.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const bodyParse = require('body-parser')

const productRoutes = require('./api/routes/products')
const orderRoutes = require('./api/routes/orders')

app.use(bodyParse.urlencoded({extended: false}))
app.use(bodyParse.json())

// Routes which handle requests
app.use('/products', productRoutes)
app.use('/orders', orderRoutes)
```

In the products.js file, I continue the routing like this:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    /*res.status(200).json({
        message: 'Handling GET requests to /products'
    })*/
    res.status(200).render("../../public")
})
```

The code I've commented out works perfectly fine, but I'm struggling to respond with the "public" folder page. I can't remember everything I've tried, but using .render or .sendFile on the "public" directory has not worked for me.

When I try to access the /products route, I'm hit with an empty error message. As it fails to return anything in the /products route, in continues down the file to an error handler. The error message is empty.

Any ideas on how to display the page with all the folder contents would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try: `app.use('/products', express.static('public'))`

This makes your "public" directory viewable from the /products route.

[express.static() docs](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: Before I handle the route, I now call app.use(express.static('..path/to/public')); It displays the public folder just fine when at the base URL, but I need the page to display when you go through the baseURL.com/products route as well. When I send a response like this: res(200).render("../../public/index.html"), I get a MODULE_NOT_FOUND error.

Comment: As in you also need '/public/index.html' to be accessible from 'baseurl.com/products/'? In that case, I believe you can define: `app.use('/products', express.static('public'))` to have the content also served from '/products/'.

Answer (score 0):

You must config path for **express static**  by :

```
//app.js | server.js

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

Then, in example you have a file as :  `/public/you.html`

In your app, you can use that file as path `/you.html`

And the same with all files type `*.js`, `*.css`,...

**Fix error cannot view error**
Run cmd `npm install ejs`
Att to **app.js**:

```
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
```

After that, you create 1 file **error.ejs** at folder **views** :

```
//error.ejs
<%=error%>
```

Goodluck

Comment: When I call app.use(express.static('./public')) first, and then call res.status(200).render("/index.html"), I get a MODULE_NOT_FOUND error. Doing mydomain.com/index.html works fine, but I want the /products route to display /index.html.

Comment: I have been updated by answer. If you want /products you must change  `get('/') ` to  `get('/product')`